# OutOfBoundsDatetime 31DEC9999

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to convert a string to date, but my date is 31DEC9999 in my original csv file

I use `pd.to_datetime("31DEC9999")`, but I get error : OutOfBoundsDatetime

I expected 9999-12-31

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Why do you need a date so far in the future anyway? If it's meant to be a placeholder, you might want to use `pd.NaT` instead.

Comment: @wjandrea - how do you put `pd.NaT` in a CSV?

Comment: @stdunbar Well, OP's talking about parsing an *existing* CSV, so that could be done with `pd.read_csv(..., na_values='31DEC9999')`.

Answer (score 1):

The max timestamp is `2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807` (check it with `pd.Timestamp.max`). `31DEC9999` exceeds this so gets converted to `pd.NaT` with `errors='ignore'`.

**Note**: the data type of output is Object (String) instead of `datetime64`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = """Date
31DEC9999
31DEC2000
31DEC1900"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
print(df)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d%b%Y', errors='coerce')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: '9999-12-31' if pd.isnull(x) else x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') )
print(df)
print('-'*10)
print(df.dtypes)
```

```
        Date                                                                                  
0  31DEC9999                                                                                  
1  31DEC2000                                                                                  
2  31DEC1900                                                                                  
         Date                                                                                 
0  9999-12-31                                                                                 
1  2000-12-31                                                                                 
2  1900-12-31                                                                                 
----------                                                                                    
Date    object                                                                                
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas 1.X uses nano-second resolution date times, which means that the maximum date is [around 2262-04-11](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html). This is a technical limitation.

The date `31DEC9999` is almost always a placeholder meaning "indefinite time in the future". You can simply replace it with a smaller placeholder also meaning "indefinite time in the future" (I've substituted various years like 2250 and 2200 at various times). Pre-process your data passing something like:

```
df['date'] = np.where(df['date'] == '31DEC9999', '31DEC2200', df['date'])
```

(Removed incorrect claim about this being fixed in Pandas 2.X. You have to fall back to standard `object` columns if you use Pandas 2.X `pd.Timestamp` objects; there are still no `datetime64[s]` columns.)

Comment: `pd.to_datetime("31DEC9999")` still raises an error on Pandas 2.0.3, so how do you get that to work? OP's using a CSV, keep in mind.